# How do I Increment an Hour in the Next Time Field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two time fields FromTime and ToTime. I need a JavaScript function to take the time input from the **fromTime** field and Add an Hour and fill the **toTime** when the focus changes.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="TFname">Time From:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="Time" name="fromTime" id="Ftime" required onfocusout="setTime()">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="TTname">Time To:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="Time" name="toTime" id="toTime" required>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function setTime() { /* The function here */ }
</script>
```

Comment: You should Include your `setTime` function in the question

Comment: Actually I could not figure the setTime() function

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` function to separate hours and minutes.

```js
$('#Ftime').on('input', function(){
var element = document.getElementById("Ftime").value;
var t = element.split(":");
var hour = parseInt(t[0])+1;
var minute = parseInt(t[1]);
  
if(minute<10){
minute='0'+minute;
}
if(hour==24)
{
hour='00';
}else if(hour<10){
hour='0'+hour;
}

  document.getElementById("toTime").value = hour+':'+minute;
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="TFname">Time From:</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="Time" name="fromTime" id="Ftime" required >
</div>
</div>                          
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="TTname">Time To:</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="Time" name="toTime" id="toTime" required >
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can play around with the script to have desired addition in the time.

Comment: Rohit Vishwakarma Hi- I Suddenly started getting this error 
The specified value "01:0" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "HH:mm", "HH:mm:ss" or "HH:mm:ss.SSS" where HH is 00-23, mm is 00-59, ss is 00-59, and SSS is 000-999.

Comment: Rohit Vishwakarma - Thanks!!! That was a great help.. Really appreciate..

Comment: Rohit Vishwakarma Hi- can you help me solve the problem in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69839943/using-jquery-to-disable-element/69840046#69840046