# Using jQuery To Disable Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have code written in ColdFusion that produces a **List** of inputs coming from an SQL Query, The code is as below:

```
<cfquery datasource="#request.dsn#" name="getProdInfo">
        Select * from dbo.Lines,dbo.[Shift],dbo.operations 
        where lineID=#form.SELLINE# and ShiftID=#form.SELSHIFT#
</cfquery>
<cfoutput query="getProdInfo">
 <div class="control-group">
    <label for="Ops">#OperationName# </label>
     <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="prods" name="prod" placeholder="Enter Production" 
        type="number"  validate="integer"  />

  <select name="Test" id="test">
     <option>Option1</option>
     <option >Option2</option>  
 </select>
 </div>
<!--- Hidden Field--->
<input class="input-small focused" id="trgt" name="Target" value="580">
</cfoutput>
```

This code produces 6 input fields, 6 selects and 6 hidden target fields (for non CFers cfoutput loops over the result set). I want to perform a jQuery that if the input field is less that 70% of the target it should enable the Select Dropdown else keep it disabled. My jQuery is as follows

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $('#prods').on('focusout', function(){
        var element1 = document.getElementById("prods").value;
        var element2 = document.getElementById("trgt").value;
        var calc = (element1/element2)*100
        if (calc<70){
            $("#test").attr('disabled','disabled')
        }
        
        });
</script>
```

The behavior is that when the first field is tested by the jQuery it disables the first select but does not apply to the other 5 selects. I think my jQuery is missing the ID of the element that is selected for input.

I hope I've cleared my point. Help appreciated

Comment: You're using jQuery but also using `getElementById`. That will get confusing after a while. Maybe stick with jQuery _or_ vanilla JS to do your element selection.

Comment: Your input `id`s are not unique, so your jQuery only affects the first one. You can make them unique by adding `#getProdInfo.currentRow#` to the IDs. Alternatively, you can use a class instead of an id, and loop over `document.querySelectorAll(assignedclassname)`. Unrelated, but your `label`'s `for` attribute is "Ops" but you have no element with id of "Ops."

Comment: @user1599011 makes a very good point about the "id".  Depending on how you'll be processing the form data later on, you might also need to create unique `name` as well.  Unrelated to your question, but extremely important, the query is vulnerable to sql injection. Always use cfqueryparam on user values like `#form#,#url#, etc...`

Comment: @user1599011 is invited to put his comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm most familiar with vanilla JS, so I'm going to use that.

I think this is what you might be trying to do. Since you're looping over your query, you need to add your event listener to each `prod` element, I don't know that an id is necessary in this case, but I always include the name and ID as standard attributes. ID must be unique, so I added a unique ID from your query. You could also use the id column from your query. You'll especially need the name if you want to submit it with a form. It may or may not be unique, depending on how you process the inputs. The `prod` class is used to select all similar elements and add the event listener.

Since I'm looking through each `prod` element here to add the event listener, we can capture that event `e` and use the event's target, `e.target` to retrieve the value.

I also updated the `for` attribute in your label. There is no element with an id of `Ops` and the id needs to be unique anyway. The label wouldn't have done anything previously.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".prod").forEach(
  function(p) {
    p.addEventListener(
      "focusout",
      function(e){
        var element1 = e.target.value;
        var element2 = document.getElementById("trgt").value;
        var calc = (element1/element2)*100
        if (calc<70){
            document.getElementById("test").disabled = "disabled";
        }//if
      }//function(e)
    )//addEventListener
  }//function(p)
);
```

```html
<cfoutput query="getProdInfo">
  <div class="control-group">
      <label for="prods#getProdInfo.currentRow#">#OperationName# </label>
      <input class="input-xlarge focused prod" id="prods#getProdInfo.currentRow#" name="prod#getProdInfo.currentRow#" placeholder="Enter Production" type="number"  validate="integer"  />

    <select name="Test" id="test">
       <option>Option1</option>
       <option >Option2</option>  
    </select>
  </div>
 </cfoutput>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the efforts I am getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at HTMLInputElement.

Comment: Also, could not understand the e.target.value logic. Thanks for helping out. A little more effort can can do the job. Thanks

Comment: @Tayyab  - A) If you'll need to track which list item is selected for which input (likely yes) both must have unique field "name's", not just "ids".  Either using currentRow or an ID from your query, like user1599011 said B) If there's only ever a single "Target" value, don't place that field inside the cfoutput loop, because that creates the same hidden field 6 times, when you only need 1 (cont'd)

Comment: C) Unrelated to the main question, but are you deliberately doing a [CROSS JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) query?  If so, best make it clearer by using an ANSI92 `CROSS JOIN`. D) Don't forget to add cfqueryparam to avoid getting hit with sql injection.

Comment: @user1599011 - Good example, just don't forget to re-enable the field if the value is >= 70 (and add back the "Target" field outside the loop) :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use .prop to set disabled to true or false. Added a link to the documentation.

```
$("#test").prop("disabled", true) -- disable
$("#test").prop("disabled", false) -- enable
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/

Answer (score -2):

Better just do it in vanilla JS and stop using jQuery lol it's 2021

```
element.disabled = true;
element.disabled = false;
```